# C++ or C#: Reading commands from a Human Interface Device(HID)

Tags: c#, c++, hid

I have this game controller pad and I need to read it's commands for another project I'm working on.

Question is: Are there any sort of libraries for C++ or C# that can communicate with HIDs as there are for Serial Ports?

Any sample code would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: If there is something you don't like about what you found by yourself, you should have said so and maybe someone here can provide you with a better solution for you. Your questions asks for “any sort of libraries”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't provide any details only some general pointers - perhaps these are helpful:

- https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary
- http://www.usbhidnetclass.org/ (commercial)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/csharp-usb-hid-driver/
- http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HIDAche.aspx?q=C%23+and+USB+HID+Devices